# How to safely disable Intel Rapid Storage Technology in UEFI BIOS?

Tags: windows-10, ahci, intel-rst

I wanted to dual-boot Ubuntu Linux 20.04 with Windows 10, but Linux said that I change mode from RST to AHCI in BIOS. I have one non-RAID disk, also there is an Intel RST controller installed on Windows. How to disable RST without crashing Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Back up your files, set your BIOS to AHCI, reinstall Windows for AHCI and then install Linux. Your Intel stick will stop working though, there is no way to get both a dual boot and optane working.